# Specific characters in command line

Tags: shell

I am working in cmd and I found a symbol that I am not sure for what reason is used. Why do we use "~/" in command line. 
Specifically in that case:

```
cp -R modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/htmlDocs2 ~/templates
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

~/ is short term for your home directory

~username/ is short term to username's home directory

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Many times while coding you need to pass the whole path of the file in cmd.

So it is just a shortcut to let the command line know that file is in the home directory itself.