# The system cannot find the file specified in command line

Tags: cmd

I have a problem executing a specific command in command line. The problem I am facing is: The system cannot find the file specified while the file is already in directory. Below is my command:

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\swagger-codegen-master\swagger-codegen master\modules\swagger-codegen\src> copy -R \main\resources\htmlDocs2 ~\test\resources\2_0\templates
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: what is `~`? That's not part of `cmd` syntax.

Comment: found your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44716265/2152082). Note: the `~` there is not parsed by `cmd`, but directly by the command `cp` itself - so it's specific to that command (which by the way is not a standard `cmd` command), you can't transfer it to another random command.

Comment: even when i omit ~ the problem still occurs

Comment: please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44722260/edit)  output of `dir \main\resources\htmlDocs2`

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Please, can you explain it simpler?

Comment: enter  `dir \main\resources\htmlDocs2`, copy it's output and [paste it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44722260/edit) (I want to double check, the source file exists, because I don't belive so)

Comment: i tried it. The system cannot find the path file

Comment: ok, so the source file isn't there. You gave an absolute path: `\main\...` means "on the current drive's root there is a `main` folder...". Is there? Probably you want to use a relative path (below your `src` folder)? Then just drop the starting `\\`. (probably the same with the destination)

Comment: I don't understand it at all because there is a main folder. if a change the dir including all the path everything is ok

Comment: anyway i will try your suggestions

Comment: a `C:\main`? Really? Because that's exactly what you tell your command.

Comment: i omitted the start '/' in source and destination and the same problem is still there

Comment: copy -R main\resources\htmlDocs2 test\resources\2_0\templates

Comment: *ouch* the file, that can't be found is `-R`. There is no `-R` parameter to the `copy` command. It's taken as the source...

Comment: so, i just need to omit -R, right?

Comment: just try it ...

Comment: The syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: It was just a mistake of mine. I just putted '/' instead of '\' somewhere. Now it works. Thank you so much. You saved my day

Comment: So tell me where can I give a point for this

Comment: Don't mind. That's nothing to get points for. You may want to bookmark [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/) a great reference site for `cmd` commands.

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147478/discussion-between-lilly-and-stephan).

Answer (score 0):

To generate `html2` documentation from Swagger Codegen, the Petstore Windows batch file is a good starting point:

```
set executable=.\modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli.jar

If Not Exist %executable% (
  mvn clean package
)

REM set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024M -DloggerPath=conf/log4j.properties
set ags=generate -i modules\swagger-codegen\src\test\resources\2_0\petstore.yaml -l html2 -o samples\html2

java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar %executable% %ags%
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/bin/windows/html2-petstore.bat